# Run a scheduled task with a user not logged in

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduled task that I have set running as a Group Managed service account. I ran `Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Task" -User GMSA$` to get the GMSA account to be run. However, when I go in to the task scheduler and try and click "run whether user is logged on or not", I get an error saying incorrect account name. [Error when clicking the Run whether user is logged on or not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaIuX.png). Is there a way to set this property via command line?

Comment: The account name is invalid. That's a pretty clear error. Does it not need a domain prefix and password supplied?. Try setting it up in the GUI - I suspect you'd get the same error.

Comment: I have tried setting it up via GUI, the account does not show up when I click check names. However, the account shows up when I try and add the permissions to folders and such.

Comment: Theses articles show how to set it up. https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2007564-using-a-group-managed-account-to-run-a-scheduled-task-on-server-2012r2 and https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Configure-Scheduled-Task-82166597